# How do I tell jquery autocomplete to display one item per line instead of the entire return value in one line?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm using Rails 5 with JQuery UI's autocomplete feature.  I'm using AJAX to get the appropriate suggestions for my textbox ...

```
$(function() {
  return $('#s').autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.get("/people/search.js", {
            s: request.term
        }, function (responseStr) {
            data = eval(responseStr);
            // assuming data is a JavaScript array such as
            // [{"value": "SpongeyB", "label": "some label" }, {"value": "SpongeyB", "label": "some label" }...]
            // and not a string
            var jsonData = new Array();
            data.forEach(function (item) {
              var jsonItem = new Object();
              jsonItem.value = item;
              jsonItem.label = item;
              var myString = JSON.stringify(jsonItem);
              jsonData.push( myString );
            });
            response(jsonData);
        });
    }
  });
});
```

However, when I type something, waht is appearing under my textbox is not a list of options, but rather the entire jsonData as a string ...

[image]

How do I tell the autocomplete function to display each item the JSON list on its own line instead of the entire JSON string?

**Edit:** In response to the answer given I change my line

```
jsonData.push( myString );
```

to

```
jsonData.push( jsonItem );
```

but I'm still getting only a single line containing all items appearing under my textbox ...

[image]

Comment: [Convert a JavaScript object into a string with JSON.stringify().](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp). I'm thinking that's not what you need or intend to do. I'm surprised `responseStr` is actually a string and not a js object. I assume you've tried passing `data` into `response` unchanged?

Comment: Exactly.  I passed the string unchanged and was then told I need to change the response to have a JSON format -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48513462/what-data-type-does-jquerys-autocomplete-function-need-to-render-the-autocomple .  Maybe I accepted taht answer too quickly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source) under **source** under **function** (which is what you are doing):

> (data) can be in any of the formats described above for simple local data.

Simple local data states:

> There are two supported formats:
>
> - An array of strings: [ "Choice1", "Choice2" ]
> - An array of objects with label and value properties: [ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]

You are doing neither of these.

After the discussion, below, it turns out the response from the server was a string representing an array of strings.

Doing:

```
$(function() {
  return $('#s').autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.get("/people/search.js", {
            s: request.term
        }, function (responseStr) {
            data = JSON.parse(responseStr);
            response(data);
        });
    }
  });
});
```

Did the trick.

Comment: Hi, I changed my line to "jsonData.push( jsonItem );" so that I'm returning an array of json objects, as indicated by your second bullet point but I'm still getting only a single item under my text box with all the items compressed into it.  I edited my question to show what's happening.

Comment: What is `responseStr` before *you do anything to it*?

Comment: It is -- ["SpongeyB","SpongeyBob","SpongeyBob2","SpongeyBob23","SpongeyBob24"]

Comment: So why aren't you just doing `response(responseStr)` *without doing anything to it* since it is already an array of strings - which is what you need. BTW, it seems not good to name the variable `responseStr` when it's not a string, it's an array.

Comment: Becuase when I did that I got an error -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48513462/what-data-type-does-jquerys-autocomplete-function-need-to-render-the-autocomple , and more importantly got dinged for not reading the documentation (even tho I did!).

Comment: Welp, you can always do `console.log(typeof(responseStr))` to see what it really is. If it is, in fact, a `string`, then you should do `JSON.parse(responseStr)` to make it into an object. Something like: `response(JSON.parse(responseStr))`. Or, possibly, `response(eval(responseStr))`, although `eval` feels yucky to me.

Comment: It was a string.  Making the block contain "data = JSON.parse(responseStr);" followed by "response(data);" solved the problem.  Thx

Comment: Well, that was a long haul. Depending on what you'll end up doing with that autocomplete, you may need to do the array of hashes approach. Tag me in a question if it gives you problems. Congratulations and good luck! Oh, BTW, I'll add an answer to your other question for future searchers. Consider whether you want to unaccept the other answer since it didn't really lead you where you needed to go.